# Symfony 3 Can't get complicated query to work with createQueryBuilder: should be displaying recommended blogposts

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, subquery, query-builder

Im building a blog website where users can post blogpost that contain many categories. I would like to display recommended blogpost beneath each separate blog. The recommended blogposts should be based on having the same category as the blogpost you're looking at.

I've first made a query in SQL and it works, but when I try to implement in it my project using createQueryBuilder I get all blogposts on the site instead of just the ones containing the same category.

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM
blog b 
    INNER JOIN
blog_category bc ON b.id = bc.blog_id
    INNER JOIN
category c ON bc.category_id = c.id 
WHERE 
c.id IN (SELECT 
        c.id
    FROM
        blog b
            INNER JOIN
        blog_category bc ON b.id = bc.blog_id
            INNER JOIN
        category c ON bc.category_id = c.id
    WHERE
        b.id = 33) and b.id != 33 group by b.id
```

As I said this query works fine but when I'm trying to use it in my Symfony project it does not work.

```
   public function findRelatedBlogs($blog_Id)
{

    $qbCat = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qbCat->select('ca.id')
        ->from('AppBundle:Blog', 'bl')
        ->join('bl.categories', 'ca')
        ->where('b.id =:blogid')
        ->setParameter('blogid', $blog_Id);

    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('b')
        ->from('AppBundle:Blog', 'b')
        ->join('b.categories', 'c')
        ->where($qb->expr()->in('c.id', $qbCat->getDQL()))
        ->where('b.id !=:blogid')
        ->groupBy('b.id')
        ->setParameter('blogid', $blog_Id);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();


}
```

I can't seem to find what's wrong.

Comment: At a glance I don't see anything wrong, but what might be useful is using getSQL() instead of getResult() & then you can see the SQL conditions the querybuilder is making. Quite useful for debugging what it is actually doing behind the scenes & where it might be not producing what you'd expect.

Comment: Always when I use subselects in Doctrine, I make something like that: `in('c.id', '('.$qbCat->getDQL().')')`. Then subselect is between `(` and `)` what SQL require to proper syntax.

Comment: As @Richard mentioned, you coukd use `getSQL()` and also you could check the Symfony debug toolbar...

Answer (score 0):

Okkey I got it to work guys turns out I made a typo in my subselect query

```
 $qbCat = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qbCat->select('ca.id')
        ->from('AppBundle:Blog', 'bl')
        ->join('bl.categories', 'ca')
        ->where('bl.id =:blogid')
        ->setParameter('blogid', $blog_Id);
```

The line "->where('b.id =:blogid') " was wrong it should have been bl.id =:blogid instead. It could not find the id because of this mistake I made..

Thanks for the help guys :)